# Hangfire Jobs Persistance with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, hangfire

I am using hangfire Server with Mongo Storage in my .net core application.
I have an API that exposes a method to enqueue Jobs.

The request params are saved into MariaDB, and a new Job is enqueued.

My Question is: what is the best way to ensure that both actions are OK. This is to avoid situation that a request is presisted but the job is not enqueued.

Situation encountered:

Request is saved in MariaDB

Exception thrown by MongoDB :

> Hangfire.BackgroundJobClientException: Background job creation failed.
>   See inner exception for details. --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by
>   peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by
>   peer

Best regards